Logical Impossibility in the classic Binary Bomb Lab (Phase 3)


Dump of assembler code for function phase_3:
   0x0000000000400f58 <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000400f59 <+1>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f5d <+5>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%r8
   0x0000000000400f62 <+10>:    lea    0x7(%rsp),%rcx
   0x0000000000400f67 <+15>:    lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400f6c <+20>:    mov    $0x402546,%esi
   0x0000000000400f71 <+25>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400f76 <+30>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x0000000000400f7b <+35>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x0000000000400f7e <+38>:    jle    0x400f96 <phase_3+62>
   0x0000000000400f80 <+40>:    cmpl   $0x7,0xc(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400f85 <+45>:    ja     0x401017 <phase_3+191>
   0x0000000000400f8b <+51>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
   0x0000000000400f8f <+55>:    jmpq   *0x402560(,%rax,8)
   0x0000000000400f96 <+62>:    callq  0x401711 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f9b <+67>:    jmp    0x400f80 <phase_3+40>
   0x0000000000400f9d <+69>:    mov    $0x71,%ebx
   0x0000000000400fa2 <+74>:    mov    $0x2d0,%edx
   0x0000000000400fa7 <+79>:    mov    $0x2f1,%ecx
   0x0000000000400fac <+84>:    jmpq   0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000400fb1 <+89>:    mov    $0x68,%ebx
   0x0000000000400fb6 <+94>:    mov    $0xc7,%edx
   0x0000000000400fbb <+99>:    mov    $0xaf,%ecx
   0x0000000000400fc0 <+104>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000400fc2 <+106>:   mov    $0x7a,%ebx
   0x0000000000400fc7 <+111>:   mov    $0x235,%edx
   0x0000000000400fcc <+116>:   mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x0000000000400fd1 <+121>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000400fd3 <+123>:   mov    $0x62,%ebx
   0x0000000000400fd8 <+128>:   mov    $0x89,%edx
   0x0000000000400fdd <+133>:   mov    $0xeb,%ecx
   0x0000000000400fe2 <+138>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000400fe4 <+140>:   mov    $0x77,%ebx
   0x0000000000400fe9 <+145>:   mov    $0x2c2,%edx
   0x0000000000400fee <+150>:   mov    $0x24b,%ecx
   0x0000000000400ff3 <+155>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000400ff5 <+157>:   mov    $0x76,%ebx
   0x0000000000400ffa <+162>:   mov    $0x36b,%edx
   0x0000000000400fff <+167>:   mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x0000000000401004 <+172>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000401006 <+174>:   mov    $0x68,%ebx
   0x000000000040100b <+179>:   mov    $0x8c,%edx
   0x0000000000401010 <+184>:   mov    $0x38e0,%ecx
   0x0000000000401015 <+189>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x0000000000401017 <+191>:   callq  0x401711 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040101c <+196>:   mov    $0x71,%ebx
   0x0000000000401021 <+201>:   mov    $0x158,%edx
   0x0000000000401026 <+206>:   mov    $0x1dd,%ecx
   0x000000000040102b <+211>:   jmp    0x40103c <phase_3+228>
   0x000000000040102d <+213>:   mov    $0x6a,%ebx
   0x0000000000401032 <+218>:   mov    $0xb7,%edx
   0x0000000000401037 <+223>:   mov    $0x121,%ecx
   0x000000000040103c <+228>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%eax
   0x0000000000401040 <+232>:   cmp    %edx,%eax
   0x0000000000401042 <+234>:   jg     0x401048 <phase_3+240>
   0x0000000000401044 <+236>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000401046 <+238>:   je     0x40104d <phase_3+245>
=> 0x0000000000401048 <+240>:   callq  0x401711 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040104d <+245>:   cmp    %bl,0x7(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401051 <+249>:   jne    0x401059 <phase_3+257>
   0x0000000000401053 <+251>:   add    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000401057 <+255>:   pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000401058 <+256>:   retq
   0x0000000000401059 <+257>:   callq  0x401711 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040105e <+262>:   jmp    0x401053 <phase_3+251>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) i r
rax            0x6a                106
rbx            0x6a                106
rcx            0x121               289
rdx            0xb7                183



Code Example!I'm working on the famous "Binary Bomb Lab" to try and shore up some holes I have in my knowledge of assembly. It's been tough so far, but I've managed to get to phase 3 and now I'm at a bit of a loss. This phase asks to work through a switch statement essentially and enter some characters of the format "%d %c %d" Now working through it I have gotten to the end, passing the format check and I think I've found the first integer and character, but I'm stuck at a certain part.
Now what I thought from this bit of code is I would need to enter an int to pass the checks, but from what I'm seeing I need to enter an int that is "LESS THAN 189" but then also "EQUAL TO 289." This is impossible. Am I misinterpreting things or what is going on that I am missing here?
EDIT -- Sorry I'm new. But I'm running x86-64 as my instruction set.

You forgot to show the code. If I had to guess, it may very well be that one condition is for the first number and the other is for the second number.

Sorry I added it to the start of the question, but the part I'm struggling with is here:
0x0000000000401040 <+232>:   cmp    %edx,%eax
0x0000000000401042 <+234>:   jg     0x401048 <phase_3+240>
0x0000000000401044 <+236>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
0x0000000000401046 <+238>:   je     0x40104d <phase_3+245>
=> 0x0000000000401048 <+240>:   callq  0x401711 <explode_bomb>
So how can I pass the jg and the je if eax needs to be smaller than edx but equal to ecx when ecx is greater than edx.

Please do not upload images of code. Also don't put relevant information only into comments. And for assembly language questions tag the processor and/or the instruction set you are using.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So pick a branch where ecx < edx.
